# is multiple Sub-Domains possible?

Tags: iis-7, dns

I was wondering what would be the easiest and best way for create multiple sub-domains that points to the same file.

I am creating a personalized website, I have a list of about 100 people that I would like for them to have their own sub-domain (i.e. http://john-smith.mysite.com/) all the different sub-domain will point to the same site (http://www.mysite.com/).

is there an easy way to do this?  I do not want to use this model: http://www.mysite.com/john-smith.

I appreciate any advice.

I use IIS 7.0 in case it makes a difference

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by creating a canonical name (cname record) in your DNS zone. Then you have to configure the virtual hosts of IIS to point on the right directory.